# How does Spring config file validate against the Spring beans XSD?

Tags: xml, spring

This might be a basic XML query but I'm a bit weak on the XML front . Hence this Query .

Consider the  tag in Spring configs

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"

xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    default-autowire="byName">
```

Here spring beans has got its XSD in the location http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd . My query is as follows .

1. Does it go to the XSD over the internet to perform the validation ?
2. If the answer to the above question is yes , When does it refer to the XSD in the spring-beans jar in the package org.springframework.beans.factory.xml ? It it when I work offline ?
3. Supposing it refers to XSD in the jar, how does it find it  ? The only XSD location the config knows is at http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd . This is not a file path pointing to something in the jar.  Does it do some pre-loading of XSDs  ? If so , who does this ? Beanfactory ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the source code for `org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver.resolveEntity(String, String)`

For how it works you can also turn on `trace` level for the following package:

```
<logger name="org.springframework.beans.factory.xml">
  <level value="TRACE" />
</logger>
```

Here's sample:

```
[xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] : Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [grgr/test/spring/_1_corecontainer/_3_context/InstantiateContainerTest.xml]
[xml.DefaultDocumentLoader] : Using JAXP provider [com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl]
[xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] : Trying to resolve XML entity with public id [null] and system id [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd]
[xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] : Loading schema mappings from [META-INF/spring.schemas]
[xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] : Loaded schema mappings: {http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core.xsd=activemq.xsd, http://activemq.org/config/1.0/1.0.xsd=activemq.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd, http://activemq.org/config/1.0=activemq.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core=activemq.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd, http://www.mycompany.com/schema/myns/my.xsd=grgr/test/spring/_9_xml/my.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scheduling/config/spring-task-3.0.xsd, http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.1.0.xsd=activemq.xsd, http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.3.0.xsd=activemq.xsd, http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.0.0.xsd=activemq.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-2.5.xsd, http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-5.2.0.xsd=activemq.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/cache/config/spring-cache-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd=org/springframework/ejb/config/spring-jee-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-2.5.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/jms/config/spring-jms-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd=org/springframework/web/servlet/config/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc.xsd=org/springframework/jdbc/config/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/transaction/config/spring-tx-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/context/config/spring-context-3.0.xsd, http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core/activemq-core-${pom.version}.xsd=activemq.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-3.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/scripting/config/spring-lang-2.0.xsd, http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd}
[xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] : Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
[xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] : Trying to resolve XML entity with public id [null] and system id [http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd]
[xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] : Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/aop/config/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
[xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] : Trying to resolve XML entity with public id [null] and system id [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd]
[xml.PluggableSchemaResolver] : Found XML schema [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd] in classpath: org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd
```

So it's generally just standard `org.xml.sax.EntityResolver.resolveEntity(String, String)`

Answer (score 2):

In the spring jars there are files called

```
META-INF/spring.schemas
```

These provide a mapping from the namespace to the path (on the classpath) where the schema can be found.

Here an example from spring-beans-3.2.1.RELEASE.jar

```
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/tool/spring-tool.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-tool-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-2.5.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.0.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.1.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd=org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/spring-util-3.2.xsd
```

The class org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.PluggableSchemaResolver looks at the spring.schemas file to find the location of the schema file.